# Best method of ROS Fuerte + Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am new to using Gazebo, but have been using ROS for a while now. I notice that ROS still packages an old version of Gazebo (1.0.2). I notice that most questions on this forum address the newer version 1.2. I need to create a mobile ground robot, use 3D mapping etc. Would there be an advantage in using the newest version of Gazebo and just writing a ROS plugin for it? Or would it be a waste of time, and perhaps using the older version of Gazebo 1.0.2 is enough?

I ask mostly for opinion based on experience if it matches my plans.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/521/best-method-of-ros-fuerte-+-gazebo/) by [Shanker Keshavdas](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/118/shanker-keshavdas/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 25 on 2012-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I would highly recommend using the lastest debian version of Gazebo, which is currently 1.3.1. This will be the most stable and feature rich version. This is also the version which we actively support.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2012-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on 2012-12-15**:
I am confused by your use of "debian" in this answer. Elsewhere the documentation says things like "We develop and run Gazebo primarily on Ubuntu Linux." Does this answer mean you are really developing Gazebo on Debian Linux? I care because Ubuntu is not installing on my Dell Precision T7600 ...

**Comment by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) on 2012-12-16**:
When we say "debian," it's in reference to a binary package, a .deb file.  That's the file format used by Debian Linux and Debian-based Linuxes, including Ubuntu Linux.  At the moment, we're only building debians for Ubuntu.  In the future, we might build debians for Debian (and other Linuxes).

**Comment by [Shanker Keshavdas](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/118/shanker-keshavdas/) on 2012-12-20**:
Thanks for your answer @nkoenig . I also assume from your answer that one should follow steps similar to those described [here](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.3/ros_enabled_model_plugin) and develop an appropriate plugin. Would be nice if I could find some predeveloped though ! :)

**Comment by [PMilani](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/92/pmilani/) on 2012-12-20**:
So for those upgrading from the version issued with ROS, what would be the best procedure to upgrade as your install guide directs ROS users to the ROS download page?